# Comparison operator in While Loop with Tuple() or List[] Python 3

Tags: python, list, variables, tuples

```
tup=(100,200,300,400,500)
userinput=0
while userinput != tup:
 userinput=int(input("Try again"))

x=userinput
```

So here is a small problem i want to take input from user until user is not entering one of the same value as in tup variable. and once user added one of them same value as is in the tup variable then i want to add/move this value to x variable.

Comment: A number is never equal to a tuple. You want to check `while userinput not in tup`. Also, the variable `userinput` is undefined.

Comment: Why a tuple and not a set?

Comment: i forgot to add userinput variable i have user variable defined befor with 0 value. but i want to compare with userinput with tup variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the "in" operator.

```
tup=(100, 200, 300, 400, 500)
usrInput = 0
while usrInput not in tup:
    usrInput = int(input("Please enter a number: "))
```

The program will keep asking the user for a number until they enter one which is in the tuple.

Comment: Thank you very much this worked really appriciate that.

Comment: You're welcome! If you consider this question "answered" please take a moment to hit the checkmark next to my answer. It gives me a reputation boost and I would really appreciate it :)

Answer (score -1):

A int from the user can't equal an entire tuple, so you should think about how you want to check the input against the values inside the tuple.

Comment: Not a very helpful answer.